# Cannot install Magento- showing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: magento, installation

I cannot install `Magento` in my `server`. What I did is, I place the `magento` folder in my server and in browser type `www.yourdomain.in/magento` . But showing 
**500 - Internal Server Error.**

How can I solve this??

I googled for solution and try some of them but no luck.

```
1.Change file permission of index.php to 755 (initially it was 777)- not worked

2.Change file permission of index.php to 644 (initially it was 777)- not worked

3.Downloaded and Put magento-cleanup.php in root and Browse to http://yourdomain.in/magento/magento-cleanup.php - still 500 - Internal Server Error.

4.Downloaded and Put magento-check.php in root and Browse to http://yourdomain.in/magento/magento-check.php - still 500 - Internal Server Error.
```

In root `Htaccess` file is not visible(I don't know whether there it is or not) so I can't remove this file(this is one solution).

So please help me . Any help is really appreciable.

**EDIT**

`www.yourdomain.in/` contains

[image]

Comment: Did you pointed the domain correctly? To test it - Create a file test.php in your a=magento directory and in that file copy this code `<?php echo "Hello Its working"; ?>` then try to access - www.yourdomain.in/magento/test.php - By doing this you will come to know the issue with magento or something else.

Comment: @GirishSH, *www.yourdomain.in/magento/test.php* also gives the seme error.

Comment: Then its problem with your setup. What it contains(What type of code) in the `www.yourdomain.in/`'s DocumentRoot?

Comment: @GirishSH, I edited the question..please refer..

Comment: Doesn't `ls -la` on the root of the site show you if you have an `.htaccess` ?
Error 500 seems to me as a directive in htaccess that your server cannot handle.